# What of these versions\options have I to download to install an Ubuntu Server that will be accessed only via SSH (no desktop mode)

Tags: server, 20.04, system-installation, ssh, versions

I am not a system engineer (I am more a software developer) and I have the following doubt.
I have to download an Ubuntu ISO in order to use it on a VCenter instance. Bascailly this will be for a server that will host a server application (it is not intended for desktop user, the connection to this machine will be done only via SSH). It will be used for a production environemtn so I suppose that a nice choise will be adopt an LTS version.

What version do you reccoment do use for a case like this one? I was checking on the Ubuntu website and I suppose that I have to download an **Ubuntu Server** version (not the desktop one).

So I was thinking to use this one: https://ubuntu.com/download/server

but what is the correct option that I need?

- **Option 1: Instant Ubuntu VMs**: what is this?
- **Option 2: Manual Server Installation**: this provide an ISO so I suppose that it could be the right one.
- **Option 3: Automated Server Provisioning**: what is this?

The guy that will install it only says to me that he need an ISO so I think that the **Option 2** is the correct one. But I am not totally sure.

Comment: You could install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server or wait a few weeks and install the newest 22.04 LTS server version. Depends on how quickly you want this done. You have given no hardware details so this is just a guess on my part.

Comment: @David no we have no time to wait. The project must start now. The hardware info are: we have to install 2 virtual instances of Ubuntu on 2 VMs having the following features: 1) VM1: 4 vCPU, 16 Gb of RAM, 80 Gb of HD. 2) VM2: 8 vCPU, 32 Gb of RAM, 500 Gb of HD. 
Is the Option 2 a valid solution for my case?

Comment: I would do it that way, I personally would not use that 3 rd party file manger commander thing but that is just me. Bottom line what you do may still need some fine tuning before being put into production. You have not mentioned any video. Or the host that the VMs run on. Please add the new info to the question via edit so everyone can easily see it without having to read comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These three options are explained on the page you linked to :)

Option 1 - Instant Ubuntu VMs - is intended to use with [Multipass](https://multipass.run/), a system that manages virtual machines on your computer in a way similar to cloud environments like eg. AWS cloud. So you can quickly deploy new instances of Ubuntu virtual machines on your computer in a similar way you do it in the cloud. However, this supports only the listed hypervisors: Virtualbox, Hyper-V (Windows), HyperKit (macOS) or KVM (Linux) - not VMWare/vCenter - so you cannot use that option (plus you need to have Multipass installed on your physical server).

Option 3 - Automated server provisioning - is intended for use with [MAAS](https://maas.io/), a system that automates and manages installation of operating systems on bare metal servers in a data center. Since you want to install a virtual machine, not a bare metal server, you cannot use this as well (plus, if you wanted to use it, you would first to have MAAS installed and working somewhere, so it's definitely an overkill for installing a single server).

Option 2 - Manual server installation - is just for all other cases, ie. for "regular" installation. So download the ISO, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Simply download and install the Server-ISO on the Server.
After this make "sudo apt install openssh-server openssh-client" and then you can access the Server over the terminal.
With the Midnight Commander (sudo apt install mc) you can navigate much better.

Comment: So OPTION 2 is it OK?  Then have I to install "openssh-server openssh-client" on this machine? What is this Midnight Commande?

Comment: This will work. The MC is like the Norton Commander or other filemanager who have two windows. It is more easy as to enter all the commands and give you a better overview if you are using the terminal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander